# "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again" when trying to use advanced drive api to convert .xls to google sheet

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a script that auto uploads .xls files into google drive from gmail and I am hitting a roadblock trying to convert the .xls file into a google sheet.  The code block below was adapted from the following article: https://www.labnol.org/code/20500-convert-microsoft-excel-xlsx-to-google-spreadsheet

the variable filename is a predefined global variable

Code Snippet:

```
function advancedDrivetest() {
  try
  { 
    var FILE = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename).next();
    var fileID = FILE.getId();
    var FILEname = "test_convert";
    var blob = FILE.getBlob();
    var resource = {
      title: FILEname
    }
    Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, {convert: true});
  }
  catch(f)
  {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }
}
```

Note:  I have enabled the advanced drive API in resources > Advanced drive services and in my google cloud project.

The code block above returns the rather unhelpful error mentioned in the title.

Comment: How long have you been receiving this error? Sometimes Google is having trouble and you just need to wait.  `if (!GmailApp) return;` checks to see if gmail is down.

Comment: This works perfectly fine in my test environment. Make sure that `filename` contains the `.xlsx` extension in its definition (for example `var filename = "nameOfFile.xlsx"`).

Comment: @RafaGuillermo thanks for the feedback I'll definitely try that.  I'm a little confused on the syntax of how this works.  Am I submitting the full name of the file to be converted or what I want the file name to be?  I've seen both in my research and google's documentation is unhelpful as usual.

Comment: @Stykes unfortunately I have not gotten this to work once.  None of the services involved are having downtime.

Comment: Upon further investigation there seems to be a formatting error with the files I have been trying to feed into this script.  Once I tried a basic test sheet it worked with no problem.  Thanks all for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Script was working fine but files I was giving it to convert were corrupt and could not be opened/converted by Google Drive API